# How to use Automatic type registration?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I bag your pardon but Automatic type registration is gone amiss for me. I've already installed LoadAssembliesOnStartup.Fody from Nuget to my project but it is necessary to add some code in my apllication for correct work of LoadAssembliesOnStartup.Fody! If I want to use, for example, '*Automatic type registration using Naming Convention*' then where I have to put this code:

```
var serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();
serviceLocator.RegisterTypesUsingDefaultNamingConvention();
```

in my application? Because now when I run my app and try to execute the following code in button command method in MainWindowViewModel:

```
private void ShowCalibrationViewExecute()
{
    var viewModel = new CalibrationViewModel();
    var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
    var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>();
    uiCompositionService.Activate(viewModel, "MainRegion");
}
```

I again have `Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredException` exception in `Catel.Core.dll`, letting me know that:

> The specified type 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered or could not be constructed. Please register type before using it.

Please point me what I should do in this case. I’ll appreciative your help very highly.

Comment: Put it in your app.xaml.cs constructor?

Comment: protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e){base.OnStartup(e); var serviceLocator=new ServiceLocator(); serviceLocator.RegisterTypeUsingDefaultNamingConvention();...}  in that manner? Please answer.

Comment: No, not OnStartup, in the constructor for app.xaml.cs.  If you don't know what a constructor is, you should stop what you're doing, grab CLR Via C#, and read it front to back.  Should take you no longer than two days.

Comment: Shell you to give me an example of how to define the constructor for app.xaml.cs? I've not faced with it before.

Comment: Sure, after you read CLR Via C#.  This is the basic of the basics.

Comment: public App() { var serviceLocator = new ServiceLocator();
            serviceLocator.RegisterTypesUsingDefaultNamingConvention(); } produces exception: 'Catel.Services.IUICompositionService' is not registered or could not be constructed. Please register type before using it'.

Comment: TypeNotRegisteredException is thrown in line: var uiCompositionService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUICompositionService>(); in command method in MainWindowViewModel.